# Is it possible to redirect stdout to a file location rather than a file descriptor?

Tags: unix

My problem is that I am redirecting stdout/stderr to log files but logrotate comes and moves files around with output then going a file descriptor without a file.

Is there is any way in shell or at the system level to redirect the output to the new file at the same location?

Comment: All I/O operations in unix are done with file handles. Short of polling the file location (repeatedly opening it before operations), you can't really do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind re-opening the file for each line, instead of:

```
$ ... > logfile.txt 2>&1
```

do:

```
$ ... 2>&1 |  while read line; do echo $line >> logfile.txt ; done
```